# Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Chaincode Error

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I'm trying to deploy a multiple organisations to Hyperledger fabric by following [this](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org) tutorial

Everything works as expected until I try to start the network: Step no 17
command:

```
composer network start -c PeerAdmin@byfn-network-org1 -n trade-network -V 0.1.14 -o endorsementPolicyFile=/tmp/composer/endorsement-policy.json -A alice -C alice/admin-pub.pem -A bob -C bob/admin-pub.pem
```

after which I get the following error:

> Error: Error trying to start business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
>   Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: chaincode error (status: 500, message: cannot get package for chaincode (trade-network:0.1.14))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the `composer network install` command completed OK for both organisations, the `composer network start` has failed for the particular *network name* and *version* specified. It is likely that there is a mismatch with the parameters for version number and network name on the command line.  Run the `composer archive list command` to see the exact name and version used in the .bna file.

You can also check what BNA has been installed on a peer by looking into the peer containers with commands similar to:

```
docker exec -it peer0.org1.example.com /bin/sh
# ls /var/hyperledger/production/chaincodes/

# exit
```

The `ls` command on the chaincodes file on the peer will show the BNAs available to be started e.g.:

```
tutorial-network.0.0.1  tutorial-network.0.0.3  
tutorial-network.0.0.2  tutorial-network.0.0.4
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ... it's working after changing the version but now it's failing at composer network ping -c alice@trede-network command 
Error : make sure the chaincode trade-network has been successfully instantiated and try again: could not find chaincode with name 'trade-network'

Comment: Does it work for Bob under step 19?  (The name of the network used on the `composer card create` command must be exactly the same as the network name used on the composer network start command - perhaps that is the problem)

Comment: No , it's failing at step 18 only , I used the same name for create and start

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar error when upgrading the business network, but for my case I had not installed the new version onto the peer. It's likely that the you did not successful install the business network onto that peer. A detailed explanation is given [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/4043)